# Japanese equivalent for 'black ice'

Tags: english-to-japanese, idioms

I was wondering if there is a Japanese equivalent for the term 'black ice'.

I googled image searched ブラックアイス , but the overwhelming majority of the results were unrelated.

Or would you say 道の上の見えない氷?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the reason why ブラックアイス doesn't mean "black ice" is because アイス itself is not typically used to mean "ice", but rather to mean "ice cream." So that's what those image results are turning up, some brand of ice cream called Black.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few terms that might be used to describe ice on a road.

- **[路面凍結]{ろめんとうけつ}** (literally "road surface freezing")
- **アイスバーン** (from the German word "Eisbahn")
- **ブラックアイスバーン** (probably the closest to what you're looking for)

The first two refer to any ice on the road, whether it's visually apparent or not. The last one is transparent ice on the road.

I found these on the Wikipedia article for 路面凍結, which I navigated to by searching for "black ice" on the English language Wikipedia and then changing the language for the article to Japanese.

Comment: +1 for describing your approach.  Useful stuff!  :)